# Trying to understand express Router function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to Node and I have a total of three JS files:

1. Index.js contains following code:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();


   /* GET home page. */
   router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
   console.log(arguments);
   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
       res.render('index', {
           title: 'sp1 - My Application',
           user: req.user
       });
   }else{
     console.log('not authentcated sending to authenticate');
       res.redirect('/login');
   }
   });
   module.exports = router;
   ```
2. SSO.js contains following code :

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var router = express.Router();
   router.get('/spinitsso-redirect', function (req, res) {
   console.log('got a redirection from idp');
   sp.sendLoginRequest(idp, 'redirect', function (url) {
       res.redirect(url);
      });
   });
   module.exports = router;
   ```
3. App.js contains following code:

   ```
   var express = require('express');
   var app = express();
   var server = app.listen(4002, function () {
   var host = server.address().address;
   var port = server.address().port;
   console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
   });
   ```

Question:

How are two different files (index.js and sso.js) are able to add middleware to the same router instance? Is this some of static property of Express where you can add router/middlerware from any JS file in your code?

Edit:
Added missing module.exports = router; in index.js and SSO.js files. How does this line of code work?

[Link](https://github.com/tngan/express-saml2/blob/master/examples/sp1/app.js) to complete code

Comment: Hello express is defined using : var express = require('express'); in each of these three files

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is missing the module.exports = router;

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hey, yeah both index.js and sso.js also contains module.exports = router;
Do you mind explaining how does that work in this case? I have added the link to complete code in the question.